# Can`t store in mysql text and this kind of emotis  from facebook even with utf8mb4_bin

Tags: mysql, encoding, character-encoding

Hi community i need your help.

I have find a problem that i don't know how to solve. The fact is that i'm getting information about posts from facebook pages. And all works fine until the doomed santa's come to the party.

I explain myself, i need to store the following text in the database:

> LLEGA LA NAVIDAD A LA DIPU

Papá Noel, el Rey Gaspar y los personajes infantiles más famosos de la tele son algunos de los protagonistas de nuestra 'Navidad en la Dipu'. Hasta el 5 de enero puedes disfrutar además de talleres infantiles, actuaciones musicales, nuestro gran Mercado Artesanal y muchas sorpresas más #NavidadEnLaDipu

Aquí te dejamos toda la programación ➡️ 'link'

and when i try to store it. i have the following error:

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6h88X.png)

I'm encoding the database with this charset as i saw that was recommended for this cases

```
  CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
USE `mydb` ;
```

All the help is welcome. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change not only de database. These things too:

```
SET character_set_client = utf8mb4;
SET character_set_results = utf8mb4;
SET character_set_connection = utf8mb4;
SET character_set_server = utf8mb4;
```

To see if you have these variables well changed use

> show variables;

Answer (score 0):

Please provide `SELECT HEX(col) ...` to help debug things.   is `F09F8E85 F09F8FBC` in utf8mb4.  `➡️` is `E29EA1 EFB88F`.

`CREATE SCHEMA .. DEFAULT CHARACTER SET` only provides the `DEFAULT`.  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...` to see what you *actually* have for the column.

See `Best practice` in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: thank you for answer, i just nedeed to include the sets to my script when i create the db and now it is fine. And when you apply the default character set and collate it is applied to all the tables by default.